# How to get rid of scheduled task "\Microsoft\Office\Office Serviceability Manager"?

Tags: windows-10, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I wanted to disable this task, but whatever it is there is something that re-enables the task again behind my back. Allegedly some component running as `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`.

I can see it from the event log (history tab of the task or `Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational`) where I disabled it:

> Event 142: User "System"  disabled Task Scheduler task "\Microsoft\Office\Office Serviceability Manager"

... and no 24 hours later it gets re-enabled and I see:

> Event 140: User "System"  updated Task Scheduler task "\Microsoft\Office\Office Serviceability Manager"

The task itself attempts to execute a file that doesn't exist on my system anyway and so it just keeps spewing errors into the event log, so how can I get rid of it for good?

The system is a fully patched Windows 10 21H2 (standalone, no Azure AD or classic AD).

Comment: Are you on a domain?

Comment: The Office Serviceability Manager is controlled by admins and helps them keep tabs of Office installations in the organization.  The task is getting re-enabled centrally (although I'm not positive if that's via GPO or what).  If it's having issues on your machine you should contact your admin and have them look into it.

Comment: @spikey_richie thanks for pointing out this missing detail. No, it's a standalone workstation. Neither AAD nor AD.

Comment: @squillman *The Office Serviceability Manager is controlled by admins and helps them keep tabs of Office installations in the organization.* ... since I am the admin of the machine that would be me, though, right?  And that's the issue there is some (software) agent that re-enables the task behind my back.

Comment: It wouldn't be you as admin of the machine, but could be you as admin of the Office installation.  Is it a MS 365 subscription?  Have you tried to repair Office?  Short of that, can you just delete the scheduled task?

Comment: @squillman The only piece of the wider "Office family" that is installed is MS Teams (profile-local installation, not system-wide). There is no other part of MS365 on this machine. Yes, deletion works. I'll see if it comes back (I think it will, based on the experience with it getting re-enabled). It seems there is some component that tries to ensure that the task is there and in a given state.

Comment: Still a part, though, but if only Teams is installed I'm not sure at that point what other pieces of MS loveliness does or doesn't get included with that...  Did you try to just torch the task?

Comment: Yep, I deleted it and will have to wait until tomorrow (at least) - I reckon - to see whether it'll come back. Will report it here then. Also will answer my own question should I find a way to get rid of it.

Comment: You might be able to sneak in the side by taking execution rights away from `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ClickToRun\officesvcmgr.exe`.  If the file doesn't exist.. put something harmless there in it's place and let it execute away. ;) As in .. copy timeout.exe to officesvcmgr.exe.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas it doesn't exist. Sure, I could also place something there or create a directory of that name (something I tend to use against malware), but I'd rather simply get rid of it. And in either case I'd hope to learn a whole lot about what pesky software components keeps adding it back.